# Agora audio call not audible in background If I don't select Audio or VOIP in the Background Mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, io, agora.io

Agora audio call not audible in background If I dont select Audio or VOIP in the background mode. If I select VOIP/Audio then I see red color status bar which I dont want to display. Can anyone help me solve this.

Comment: I think the red bar is set by OS and you can not remove it for security and privacy.

Comment: @skaak but some of the other apps doesn't have red bar while using audio calling feature.

Comment: Hi Ajith - I've seen green status and red status and I think green is when making a call and red when recording audio. I think you will have one of these. I understand you don't want red. Does that mean green will be fine?

Comment: @skaak I dont want to show anything on the status bar. Neither green nor red when the app is in the background.

Comment: Not possible AFAIK.